# Should I use a accessor that calculates the price or a separate field for price calculation?

Tags: laravel

Sorry because of the title, it may not be that explanatory. Well I have products where the price consists of a multiplication using a currency and the product's base (price) value. I think I have two options to create or access this price result.

- I could periodically (cron or scheduling) multiply each products currency and base and then place the result to its price field.
- I could create an accessor which returns the multiplication of the currency and base as price attribute each time I access the model.

I guess the first approach needs some extra process for the scheduled calculations (depending on the frequency) which could be a drawback. The latter would only make the calculation when the product is called. But don't know what happens when I call a lot of products. Well for listing I can use pagination but for other product processes I would need large amounts of prıducts. I am not quite sure and haven't that much experience and knowledge about accessors. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Does a product only have one currency?

Comment: @Remul Yes it has one currency. Actually a belongsTo relation to possible many currencies but in the end it is affected only by one.

Comment: You could use model events to calculate the price whenever a product is stored / updated, the drawback of using an accessor is that they are not available when using the query builder for methods like `orderBy`, `where` etc.

Comment: @Remul `not available when using the query builder for methods like orderBy, where etc.` this is an important point that needs to be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless we are talking about thousands and thousands of products being returned, an accessor should do the job well enough.

I would suggest doing this as the first approach and then checking to see what impact it has upon performance using debug tools. If it is an acceptable change in performance, stick with it.

Pre-calculating the prices and storing them in either a database or cache seems like a lot of work if the performacne increase would be negligible.

Comment: Well I guess there could be up to 20k products processed at once. The products need to be shared to other platforms every 3-5 minutes. From the other side the currency is updated as well every 2 minutes. It seems like each aproach needs to `checking to see what impact it has upon performance` anyway.

Comment: Ok, so I assume this something like an API call which returns 20K products as part of a single request? With the products changing in value based off of something like a price index?

Comment: Actually my (20k) products are (periodically) updating other platforms using their APIs.